# Как я могу в .net сериализовать GUID без дефисов?

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Как я могу в .net сериализовать в формат XML GUID без дефисов?

Структура выходного документа не важна.

Необходимо, например, вместо `<RqUID>5c88f0fc-9edf-4428-9ee1-b28ba2a5f03c</RqUID>`
получить `<RqUID>5c88f0fc9edf44289ee1b28ba2a5f03c</RqUID>`

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Можно вывести guid без дефисов `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`, [см. тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx). Это то, что ищете?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом «сериализовать»? Расскажите о вашей задаче.

Comment: @VladD а по-моему тут довольно просто можно понять (в частности, по метке xml), что автор хочет преобразовать экземпляр `Guid` в xml-документ. Правда структура желаемого документа отсутствует, но это не мешает оформить простой пример с `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @Nikita: Хм. Если это просто XML-сериализация, то зачем нужен нестандартный формат?

Comment: @Nikita, да, при преобразовании GUID в xml , проставляются дефисы, мне нужен формат без них. Пример не составил, потому что пишу с мобильного, т к комп за которым я работаю на данный момент, не вызывает у меня никакого доверия, для авторизации личных аккаунтов. Надеюсь на понимание сообщества)) структура не важна, лишь бы вместо <RqUID>5c88f0fc-9edf-4428-9ee1-b28ba2a5f03c</RqUID> получить это : <RqUID>5c88f0fc9edf44289ee1b28ba2a5f03c</RqUID>

Comment: @VladD, я предположил, возможно есть какой-нибудь атрибут, который позволяет менять формат, ведь при выводе GUID в string, этот формат меняется стандартно!

Comment: @BorzTorkoy: Вряд ли, ведь правильный формат с дефисами. Покажите вашу структуру данных, можно сделать какой-нибудь хак.

Comment: @VladD, не, хак мне не желательно, если это не предусмотрено по стандарту, то мне необходимо, чтоб клиентская сторона с которой сообщается моя часть, использовала стандартный формат, там уже другие разработчики...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В качестве воркэраунда можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
public class Data
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore] // это не сериализуем
    public Guid Y { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Y")] // а вместо Y сериализуем вот это
    public string YSerializable
    {
        get => Y.ToString("N");
        set => Y = Guid.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

Получаем XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <X>1</X>
  <Y>0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10</Y>
</Data>
```

Минус: лишнее свойство, нужное лишь для сериализации.

---

В качестве альтернативы, можно реализовать `IXmlSerializable`. Но это, наверное, больше мороки.

Comment: в итоге пришлось так и сделать)) Спасибо

Comment: @BorzTorkoy: Пожалуйста!